# Unexpected status from Android DownloadManager

Tags: android, android-download-manager

I am getting back a status of 200 from this code:

```
 String status = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS));
```

200, however, is not one of the known status codes:

```
DownloadManager.STATUS_PAUSED
DownloadManager.STATUS_PENDING
DownloadManager.STATUS_RUNNING
DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL
DownloadManager.STATUS_FAILED
```

So why is a 200 being returned from cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS)) ?

NOTE: Testing on api 10 with the same code and the same sample download file, I only see expected status values, but testing on API 14 or API 17 I am seeing the 200 status.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to get the status is

```
int status = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS));
```

Specifically, the `Cursor` returned from `DownloadManager` is a `DownloadManager.CursorTranslator`, which overrides `getInt()` for handling `COLUMN_STATUS`, while calling `getString()` just returns the raw values for that column.